# https - ssl - relative path approach not working?

Tags: asp.net, html, ssl

I am using a master page layout etc, so all the pages have some parts of it coming from one master page or another.

Now, checkout is one of these pages, and it needs to be secure. In my master page, I am using relative path to images and Url's, and these images end up with "http".  I thought that if I am using relative path, my master page AND css file automatically use https instead of http if the page is secure? Apparently it does not, when I right click on an image, it still has "http" instead of "https" ans same goes for URL path.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this [great article](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html) by Ned Batchelder which shows schema relative URLs:

```
<img src='//fast.cdn.net/pix/smiley.jpg' />
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: I am not getting images from any other site.  They are all local to my website.

Comment: But the question is: but how do you do this with a *relative* URL?

Answer (score 1):

When the images come back as http are you checking this from your local dev or production?  I thought I had this problem before but then realized my dev environment was always http and that the relative path would work in production because there it would be https.